# Text not appearing in Bevy 0.11

Tags: bevy

I'm using Bevy 0.11, which has a default font. Unfortunately I'm struggling to get the text to actually show up. I have confirmed that my system is running and that the dep I'm using is actually 0.11.

Relevant code:

```rust
fn lobby_startup(mut commands: Commands) {
    commands.spawn(Camera3dBundle::default());

    // All this is just for spawning centered text.
    commands
        .spawn(NodeBundle {
            style: Style {
                width: Val::Percent(100.0),
                height: Val::Percent(100.0),
                position_type: PositionType::Absolute,
                justify_content: JustifyContent::Center,
                align_items: AlignItems::FlexEnd,
                ..default()
            },
            background_color: Color::rgb(0.43, 0.40, 0.38).into(),
            ..default()
        })
        .with_children(|parent| {
            parent
                .spawn(TextBundle {
                    style: Style {
                        align_self: AlignSelf::Center,
                        justify_content: JustifyContent::Center,
                        ..default()
                    },
                    text: Text::from_section(
                        "Entering lobby...",
                        TextStyle {
                            font: Default::default(),
                            font_size: 96.,
                            color: Color::BLACK,
                        },
                    ),
                    ..default()
                })
                .insert(LobbyText);
        })
        .insert(LobbyUI);
}
```

Full repro possible like this:

```
git@github.com:banool/plane.git
cd plane
git checkout 48b6318602a7deefeacfa2648f22b0e77ffd5611
cargo run
```

Comment: Interestingly other systems later on fail if they try to query LobbyText, so something tells me the entity isn't being spawned / the component attached correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. font: Default.default() didn't work for me. Try to load font as resource.

1. Add new parameter to **loby_startup** function: **asset_server: Res<AssetServer>**

```
fn lobby_startup(mut commands: Commands, asset_server: Res<AssetServer>)
```

2. change TextStyle, font property

   ```
   text: Text::from_section(
      "Entering lobby...",
       TextStyle {
          font: asset_server.load("path_to_some_ttf_font"),
          font_size: 96.,
           color: Color::BLACK,
       },
   ),
   ..default()
   ```